# C# Creating an ExcelFile object from an ExcelFile object

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a csv containing 200k records. I want to take 5,000 record chunks from that csv, create a new ExcelFile object for each set of those record chunks with column headers, process them, then delete the new object once processed. I need to be able to pass the ExcelFile object into a method for processing.

Here's what I am using to read in the initial file ...Im hoping theres a way to create new ExcelFile objects using a range or something similar.

```
    ExcelFile excelFile = new ExcelFile();
    ExcelParcer excelParcer = new ExcelParcer();
    excelFile = excelParcer.processFile(filePath, true);
    Excel.Range xlRange = excelFile.range;
    int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count; 
    int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
```

Thanks ahead of time for your input. We have an existing process and need the least invasive way of making the change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with CSV then one way to do it. May be it's help you.
Like,

---

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("CSV file path");
            for (int j = 0; j < xlRange.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
                for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(sr.ReadLine()+Environment.NewLine);
                }
                File.AppendAllText(j.ToString() + ".csv",sb.ToString());
            }
```